# scala pattern matching error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.hd$1()Ljava/lang/Object;

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, runtime-error

I wrote the following code:

```
def combine(trees: List[CodeTree]): List[CodeTree] = {
    if (trees.length >= 2) makeCodeTree(trees.head, trees.tail.head) :: trees.tail.tail
    else trees
}
```

It gives the following result (what I would expect):

```
res0: List[patmat.Huffman.CodeTree] = List(Fork(Leaf(a,3),Leaf(c,3),List(a,c),6), Leaf(b,6))
```

The problem with my code is that it doesn't look nice. 
So I decided to refactor it to (with pattern matching):

```
def combine(trees: List[CodeTree]) : List[CodeTree] = trees match {
    case t1 :: t2 :: ts => makeCodeTree(t1,t2) :: ts
    case _ => trees
}
```

I would expect the same result as my previous code example.

But I don't understand why I got this error (NoSuchMethodError) in my Scala worksheet. How do I fix it?

Please note that the following code works with pattern matching, but (as aspected) I got a wrong answer.

```
def combine(trees: List[CodeTree]): List[CodeTree] = trees match {
    case t1 :: t2 :: ts => ts
    case _ => trees
}
```

Comment: If I replace ``CodeTree`` with ``String``, I do not have any problem with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CodeTree is not a case class you need to create a companion object with apply and unapply methods.  With a case class you get those methods for free in the background and they are necessary for pattern matching.